# Ubuntu budgie eduroam wifi problem

Tags: wireless, budgie

I'm having problems trying to connect to my university's wifi. It's eduroam. It connects and 1 or 2 minutes later I lose conection. This happens every time. It only happens with eduroam so far. It works propertly in my house.

System
Computer: Lenovo y700
Distribution: Ubuntu 17.04
Kernel: 4.10.0-35-generic

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.   
802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]

Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:a814]

Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae

Kernel modules: rtl8821ae, wl

03:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
[AMD/ATI] Bonaire XT [Radeon R9 M280X] [1002:6646] (rev ff)

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Is there anything else you need?